# React native fetch response bad characters

Tags: react-native, http, post, encoding, request

So i need to communicate with server. Here is my code

```
fetch('http://localhost:444/xml', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'STW-Authorization': 'Basic YmFybmk6YmFybmkxNTY=',
      'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
    },
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.status)
    return response.text()
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data)
  })
```

And this prints badly encoded characters like �

Here is the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<rsp:responsePack version="2.0" id="" state="error" programVersion="12003.3 (21.11.2018)" ico="" note="Nebol n�jden� �iadny s�bor pre spracovanie." xmlns:rsp="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/response.xsd" xmlns:rdc="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/documentresponse.xsd" xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd" xmlns:lst="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list.xsd" xmlns:lStk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list_stock.xsd" xmlns:lAdb="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list_addBook.xsd" xmlns:acu="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/accountingunit.xsd" xmlns:inv="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/invoice.xsd" xmlns:vch="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/voucher.xsd" xmlns:int="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/intDoc.xsd" xmlns:stk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd" xmlns:ord="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/order.xsd" xmlns:ofr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/offer.xsd" xmlns:enq="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/enquiry.xsd" xmlns:vyd="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/vydejka.xsd" xmlns:pri="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prijemka.xsd" xmlns:bal="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/balance.xsd" xmlns:pre="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prevodka.xsd" xmlns:vyr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/vyroba.xsd" xmlns:pro="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/prodejka.xsd" xmlns:con="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/contract.xsd" xmlns:adb="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/addressbook.xsd" xmlns:prm="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/parameter.xsd" xmlns:lCon="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list_contract.xsd" xmlns:ctg="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/category.xsd" xmlns:ipm="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/intParam.xsd" xmlns:str="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/storage.xsd" xmlns:idp="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/individualPrice.xsd" xmlns:sup="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/supplier.xsd" xmlns:prn="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/print.xsd" xmlns:sEET="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/sendEET.xsd" xmlns:act="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/accountancy.xsd" xmlns:bnk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/bank.xsd" xmlns:sto="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/store.xsd" xmlns:grs="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/groupStocks.xsd" xmlns:acp="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/actionPrice.xsd" xmlns:csh="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/cashRegister.xsd" xmlns:bka="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/bankAccount.xsd" xmlns:ilt="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/inventoryLists.xsd" xmlns:nms="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/numericalSeries.xsd" xmlns:pay="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/payment.xsd" xmlns:mKasa="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/mKasa.xsd" xmlns:gdp="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/GDPR.xsd" xmlns:ftr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/filter.xsd"></rsp:responsePack>
```

The note text should be

```
Nebol nájdené žiadny súbor pre spracovanie.
```

Please help me found out the answer.

Comment: I'd try `encoding="ISO-8859-2"`  in the XML declaration. In any case, switch to [UTF-8 Everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/)…

Comment: i cant switch to utf 8 because this is not my server, but i need to get answer for tihs.